# Dotnetbar Tab Control TabItem Closing Prompt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol, dotnetbar

I am using dotnetbar with visual studio 2010.

I added dotnetbar tabcontrol to my form, with close buttons on tabs visible.
I just wanna get a message box prompt, when closing a tab by clicking on their close button on the tab, whether to close it or not.
If "Yes" clicked, tab closes.... else not.

I can't find a close button click event or any other method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use TabItemClose event and if needed set Cancel=true on event arguments to prevent closing.

Comment: Could you pls post example code how to do it. I didn't get it properly.

Comment: How to set Cancel=true on event arguments to prevent closing.